# SQL - summing up minutes in the table for all the rows with the same month as their date and store it in a column for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as follow:

```
id    |minutes  |sumOfMinutes|Date
_______________________________________
1     | 5       |          |   20141106

1     | 7       |          |   20141106

2     | 1       |          |   20141106

2     | 9       |          |   20141106

3     | 8       |          |   20141106
```

How can I store sum of minutes in the third column for rows under the same month, so that i have:

```
id    |minutes  |sumOfMinutes| Date
_____________________________________
1     | 5       | 12         |   20141106

1     | 7       | 12         |   20141112

2     | 1       | 18         |   20141006

2     | 9       | 18         |   20141007

3     | 8       | 18         |   20141009
```

Comment: which dbms, oracle or ms sql

Comment: How are you getting from the dates in the original table to the dates in the result table?  Are the dates being stored as an integer or a date field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUM() and Group by

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.minutes, SUM(monthTot.minutes), table1.Date 
FROM table 1
JOIN table1 AS monthTot ON
    MONTH(monthTot.date) = MONTH(table1.date)
GROUP BY table1.id, table1.minutes, table1.Date
```

Comment: yes.. but how can i store this sum for that month on each row? i tried this before and what i get is values for multiple rows but i need to have the value on each row

Answer (score 0):

sum with partition by option can be used to achieve this.

```
select  id, [minutes], 
        sum([minutes]) over ( partition by month([date]) ) as sumOfMinutes,
        [Date] 
 from Table1
```